# Dimensions of C-style arrays in typedefs

Tags: c++, arrays, typedef

I have a question about the dimensions of C-style arrays in C++. In using declarations/typedefs the dimensions seems strange when using more than one dimension. For example:

```
using A1 = int[23]; //! << A1 = int[23]
using A2 = A1[4];   //! << A2 = int[4][23]

std::cout << std::is_same<int[23][4], A2>::value << std::endl; //false
std::cout << std::is_same<int[4][23], A2>::value << std::endl; //true
```

I thought that the type of A2 would be int[23][4] and not int[4][23]. The same behaviour is observed is observed in the snippet below:

```
template<typename T>
struct ArrayTest;

template<typename T, size_t N>
struct ArrayTest<T[N]>
{
    using type = T;
};

ArrayTest<int[23][2][45]>::type A3;  //! T is int[2][45], N is 23
```

In this example I thought the type would be int[23][2] and not int[2][45]. 
Does anyone know why the types are deduced like this? I have tried to find an explanation in the standard, but I guess I have not looked hard enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does anyone know why the types are deduced like this?

```
using A2 = A1[4];
```

`A2` is a length 4 array of `A1` objects.

```
using A1 = int[23];
```

`A1` is a length 23 array of `int`. So the type of `A2` is length 4 array of length 23 `int`, or `int[4][23]`.

Comment: To add: `int[4][23]` is by convoluted _snail rule_ of reading C-declarations is _array of 4 arrays of 23 integers_. http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=int+x[4][23]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It both makes sense and is somewhat strange. Especially in the template. To fetch the last dimension([45]) I have to do an `std::extent<T,2>::value` (no depencance on the N parameter) or explicitly add all three dimensions with their own `size_t` parameters.